# Upgrade angular2 to version 2.4.1 from 2.1.1

Tags: angularjs, angular, package.json, angular2-upgrade

I want to update angular2 from version 2.1.1 to 2.4.1
I have used [this](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-webpack-starter-and-angular2-highchart) seed project to start with.

My package.json was like

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "5.1.1",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.29",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "0.15.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Then I updated package.json file to below code

```
{   "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",   "version": "5.4.1",   "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",   "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"   ],   "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",   "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",   "license": "MIT",   "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack",    "i18n": "ng-xi18n"   },   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "parse5": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "0.15.0"   },     "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"   },   "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"   }, "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"   } }
```

I am able to run but getting below error when i changed package.json and removed node_modules folder and run command npm install --save

```
[at-loader] node_modules\@types\protractor\index.d.ts:11:34
    Cannot find name 'webdriver'.

[at-loader] src\app\app.e2e.ts:9:27
    Property 'getTitle' does not exist on type 'IBrowser'.

[at-loader] src\app\app.e2e.ts:27:45
    Property 'getText' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.

[at-loader] src\app\home\home.component.spec.ts:38:17
    Property 'localState' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

[at-loader] src\app\home\home.component.spec.ts:42:19
    Property 'title' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

[at-loader] src\app\home\home.e2e.ts:10:27
    Property 'getTitle' does not exist on type 'IBrowser'.

[at-loader] src\app\home\home.e2e.ts:16:48
    Property 'getText' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve these errors by doing following changes.

1)added import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
  in app.e2e.ts and home.e2e.ts

2)Remove below 2 statements from home.component.spec.ts

> it('should have default data', () => {
>       expect(comp.localState).toEqual({ value: '' });   });
>
> it('should have a title', () => {
>       expect(!!comp.title).toEqual(true);   });